# MSE of WLS estimator with biased measurements

Tags: linear-regression, parameter-estimation, weighted-least-squares

(also posted on CV, but I will try here too)
I am trying to find out if what I am looking at is a known problem.
I am considering the case of weighted least squares, and I am trying to find the optimal weights of biased measurements. I have shown what the value of the weight must be to minimize the MSE of this WLS estimator.
In other words, if we know the squared bias of some measurements, we can lower the MSE by including them in the parameter estimator, and to include them in the WLS, we need to compute a (optimal) weight.
**Is this a thing? Where can I read more about it?**
All hints are appreciated.

*Problem:*

We want to estimate $\beta$ in
$$
y_i = \beta x_i + \epsilon_i
$$
where $\epsilon_i$ are Gaussian, some with zero mean, some have nonzero mean, while $\beta, x_i$ are deterministic.
We assume to know the *squared* bias of those $\epsilon_i$ that are biased (in practice this is estimated), and we also know the noise of the unbiased measurements.

I encountered this problem as I am working on a data fusion problem, where one information source will be biased. The linear case is just for completion, to look at optimums in ideal situations.
(I have proved what the optimal weights are for the WLS both when this bias is deterministic and Gaussian distributed)

Side note: I keep reading about how MMSE estimator is unbiased, without the sources pointing to any assumption on the noise. Without assumptions on the noise (zero mean) it can not be true, right?

Comment: If you only know the _squared_ bias this doesn't work. But if you know the bias $e$ of $\epsilon_i = e + \sigma_i$, you can adapt the problem from $y_i = \beta x_i + \epsilon_i$ to $y_i - e = \beta x_i + \sigma_i$, where $\sigma_i$ has zero mean.

Comment: If you only know the squared bias (and not the sign of the bias), it means you have $y_i = \beta x_i + e + \sigma_i$, where you know $|e|$ but not sgn$(e)$. In this case I'm not sure there is much you can do. I'll think about it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I believe that you can indeed include it in the WLS estimator, and it will reduce the MSE, if you apply the correct weight. It is clear that if you know the actual bias you can make a correction, but that is not what we assume, at the moment ... :)

Comment: Ok. I guess you have a sample of $\{x_i,y_i\}$ pairs, with ${i=1,...,n}$. Do you have some $x_i = x_j$? Or are your $x_i$ all different?

Comment: I was not going to assume anything about the values of the $x_i$'s, so they may be the same. Does it make a difference? I am not looking to solve it, because I already did, but I am looking for some keywords or theorems that relate to this, such as a " biased MMSE"-version of the Gauss-Markov theorem.